# Specify path to site descriptor in maven

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I am generating a site for a project of mine and I want to place the sitedescriptor.xml in a specific location. How would I reflect this in my project's pom? Is there something like this that I can do:

```
<descriptors>
<descriptor>path/to/my/xml </descriptor>
</descriptors>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you like to locate the site descriptor into a specific location? What's the purpose behind that? Why not using the defaults?

Comment: @khmarbaise Because of the structure of the structure of my project and the policies I have to follow.

Comment: Use the `siteDirectory` option of the maven-site-plugin, but i can't recommend that. The policies are a problem, but they have to be reconsidered in relationship with Maven otherwise you will start to fight against maven and in the end you would loose the combat.